# Jquery UI Autocomplete overflow covered by Modal

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, modal-dialog

I want to use Jquery UI autocomplete in Modal, but the autocomplete is covered by Modal.

[image: autocomplete]

[This](http://jsbin.com/pexali/edit?html,css,js,output) is the live example. I use

```
.ui-autocomplete.ui-widget {
  font-size: 12px;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

but not working.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `overflow: visible` from `.ui-autocomplete.ui-widget` and add it to `.ui-dialog`:

```
.ui-dialog {
  overflow:visible;
}
```